# Context in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

When I install the context module in Drupal 7, it works but does not display all the options for reactions. So I created my context, but was not able to built it like I wanted because the "Block" reaction was unavailable. I had read that clearing the cache will bring this option up, so I cleared the cache, but now my contexts stopped being interactive.

Behavior happening:

- Select a condition/reaction from contexts and no options appear. I cannot input any information or select any options.

Expected behavior:

- Select a condition/reaction from contexts and options appear (if I select views, I should see various views appear. If I select path, I should be able to input a path).

What can I do to fix this? It does not appear to be on the Context bug list.

Comment: What options is it showing? What options are you expecting and not seeing? Also even context has add ons which apply additional reactions (for example http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets)

Comment: What I expect: Select an action (say Views) and a series of options appear (List of views available to the context module). What actually happens: I select an action and nothing appears. The same thing is true with reactions: I select Blocks and no list of blocks appear. Does this help to clarify?

Comment: Which version [of context / context_ui] are you using?

Comment: I am currently using the most up-to-date recommended build. -> 7.x-3.0-beta4

Comment: I recall this happening a long time ago, and think it was due to a javascript conflict. Sorry I can't offer more information (it's long since solved), but it's a place to start looking. Disable any modules that add JS, one by one, and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. If it is a js problem, then I think I know what might be causing it... I will post the solution if I get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem just a few days ago. And it was not contained only to context. The usual drag and drop behaviour for rearranging fields for example also was not working. I only got weights. Everything using javascript was broken. It would seem something is messing up the jquery. Perhaps drupal loads a javascript that needs jquery before loading jquery?

The problem showed up after installing BeautyTips and CalendarTips that use jquery to create pop-up tips. Even after unistalling them didn't change the situation.

Then I enabled the js aggregation from the admin>config>development>performance menu and everything works. Perhaps you could try the following:

- Enable/Disable the js aggregation
- Forcibly delete the contents of sites>default>files>js so drupal will have to regenerate them
- Clear your caches
- Keep firebug open to the script tab and watch if you get any errors.

Good luck

Comment: This helped me resolve the problem. Thank you so much!